# How to render TouchableWithoutFeedback and TouchableNativeFeedback as tab buttons with createBottomTabNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-navigation-bottom-tab

I am trying to use the `createBottomTabNavigator` (from `@react-navigation/bottom-tabs` v5). The only thing I couldn't change was the tab button. The default is good, but I want to use the `TouchableNativeFeedback` on Android and `TouchableWithoutFeedback` (the default) on iOS.

So I created [this snack](https://snack.expo.io/@rafatcb/bottom-tab-navigation) and the only Touchable that rendered correctly is the `TouchableOpacity`, the others are visually broken and have no effect when pressed (the navigation isn't working).

What is missing to properly render the `TouchableNativeFeedback` and `TouchableWithoutFeedback`?

```js
import React from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  TouchableOpacity,
  TouchableWithoutFeedback,
  TouchableNativeFeedback,
  StyleSheet,
} from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

const ScreenWithoutFeedback = () => <Text>Without Feedback</Text>;
const ScreenOpacity = () => <Text>Opacity</Text>;
const ScreenNativeFeedback = () => <Text>Native Feedback</Text>;

const buttonWithoutFeedback = (props) => (
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback {...props} />
);

const buttonOpacity = (props) => <TouchableOpacity {...props} />;

// I didn't set the Ripple yet because it isn't rendering correctly
const buttonNativeFeedback = (props) => <TouchableNativeFeedback {...props} />;

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <TabNavigator.Navigator
        initialRouteName="Collect"
        tabBarOptions={{
          activeTintColor: '#2962ff',
          inactiveTintColor: '#666',
          labelStyle: {
            fontSize: 12,
          },
          tabStyle: {
            maxWidth: 168,
            minWidth: 80,
            paddingHorizontal: 12,
            paddingTop: 8,
            paddingBottom: 12,
          },
          style: {
            alignItems: 'center',
            height: 56,
          },
        }}>
        <TabNavigator.Screen
          name="Without"
          component={ScreenWithoutFeedback}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="account" color={color} size={24} />
            ),
            tabBarLabel: 'WithoutFeedback',
            tabBarButton: buttonWithoutFeedback,
          }}
        />
        <TabNavigator.Screen
          name="Opacity"
          component={ScreenOpacity}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="settings" color={color} size={24} />
            ),
            tabBarLabel: 'Opacity',
            tabBarButton: buttonOpacity,
          }}
        />
        <TabNavigator.Screen
          name="Native"
          component={ScreenNativeFeedback}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ color }) => (
              <MaterialCommunityIcons name="logout" color={color} size={24} />
            ),
            tabBarLabel: 'NativeFeedback',
            tabBarButton: buttonNativeFeedback,
          }}
        />
      </TabNavigator.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Current result:

[image: Bottom tab bar, only the TouchableOpacity works]

---

I know there is a `createMaterialBottomTabNavigator` (from `@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs`), but using it I would need to configure more things that I couldn't make it work in my tests.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To fix it, render a `<View>` inside the Touchable and render the `children` inside that view. Also, the `style` prop should be passed to the `<View>`.

`TouchableNativeFeedback`

```js
const buttonNativeFeedback = ({ children, style, ...props }) => (
  <TouchableNativeFeedback
    {...props}
    useForeground={true}
    background={TouchableNativeFeedback.Ripple('#2962ff1f', true)}>
    <View style={style}>{children}</View>
  </TouchableNativeFeedback>
);
```

`TouchableWithoutFeedback`

```js
const buttonWithoutFeedback = ({ children, style, ...props }) => (
  <TouchableWithoutFeedback {...props}>
    <View style={style}>{children}</View>
  </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
);
```

[Snack with the working code.](https://snack.expo.io/@rafatcb/bottom-tab-navigation-fixed)

[image: Bottom tab navigation properly rendered.]